# Printing Array in HTML Table Using Lodash?

Tags: javascript, html, lodash

Hi im trying to  print some elements from an array in a HTML using lodash.

Ive got this:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Age</td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td> <script _.map(gillfamily,="" "name")=""><script/> </td>
      <td> <script_.map(gillFamily, "age")/></script> </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

but it just prints the titles Name and Age. How do I get the values from the Array into the page using lodash. (I need to use this as the task specifies it)
Thanks

Comment: The script tags there won't magically transform themselves into `td`s and `tr`s. You'll have to manipulate the DOM (create new `td`s and append them to the `table`)

Comment: Please include a [mcve]. Explain what you're using clearly and what you expect it to do.

Answer (score 1):

The result of the content of the `script` tags aren't printed out in the location of the script tag (it doesn't work like `echo` in PHP :D ). The scripts need to interact with the DOM to manipulate it's content.

For example,

```
<script>
document.querySelectorAll('tr td')[0].innerHTML = _.map(gillFamily, "age")
</script>
```

Comment: You can not set innerHTML with `querySelectorAll`

Comment: My bad. Updated it.